# Присвоить Bitmap к ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

Во фрагменте получаю строку с `URI` файла с фотографией. Далее пытаюсь занести изображение в `ImageView`, но после попытки `ImageView` остается пустым. При этом файл, который я пытаюсь получить, существует, также у `bitmap` показывается ширина, высота и другие свойства, но сам `Bitmap` в `ImageView` не попадает. В чем дело?

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
File file = new File(URI.create(bundle.getString("photo")));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultImage)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: а версия андроид какая?

Comment: @P.Ilyin версия 4.4

Comment: В общем, по коду сложно судить, т.к. не ясно как именно `photo` попадает в Bundle. Предлагаю избежать промежуточного маппинга (из строки в `URI`, потом из `URI` в файл, потом из файла в битмапу...). Помещайте в `Bundle` сразу файл (объект `File`) с картинкой. `File` реализует интерфейс `Serializable`. Таким образом вы пропустите два шага маппинга, в которыХ, возможно, закралась ошибка